# Determining which properties to serialize in a class that's passed over a webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, serialization

I'm using NHibernate to administer my entities, and to have lazy loading enabled I need to make my properties return an IList<>. Problem is that .NET throws an exception as it can't serialize an interface when I'm trying to pass the entity. This makes perfect sense.

What I need to know is how I can control which fields to serialize, and which not to? My best bet so far is to work around this problem by copying the contents of IList<> into a List<> before serializing the object, but to do that I need to tell .NET that I don't want the IList<> property serialized :)

Comment: Just for clearness: not serializing IList is a bug in XmlSerializer. If you are able, then switch to WCF or replace the serializator to DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Can't switch to WCF as it's part of a school assignment where the requirements state that we needs to use a "normal webservice" :)

Comment: WCF _is_ normal web services! WCF is the replacement for the old ASMX web services. If teacher doesn't like that, have me talk to me!

Comment: Hehe, don't worry.. He wants us to replace the ASMX-part with WCF later on :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to let you guys know that I found the answer to be the 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore] attribute :)

Answer (score -1):

MSDN has an area on [Serializing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(VS.71).aspx), but what you want is [Selective Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axwwbcs6(VS.71).aspx). So basically, you can mark any property you don't want serialized with the attribute, [NonSerialized].  There is an example in the second link.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. You helped me a lot with those resources, however the correct attribute was System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore , which I'll post in a new answer for further reference.

Comment: Your welcome.  I should have asked if you were doing binary or XML serialization.  It has been a long time since I did serialization in .NET.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but since I'm using a webservice, ain't it supposed to be soap, which in turn means that it needs to be XML-serialization? :P

Comment: Yes, you need XML serialization. This is not the answer to your question.